# EHCache - org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Persistence directory already locked by another process

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, ehcache-3

I am running a struts2 application am I have to implement a cache to cache certain responses. I have used EHCache and created a helper class to initialize and configure the cache as follows:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.CacheManager;
import org.ehcache.PersistentCacheManager;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;

import gate.util.Pair;
import net.ha.apserver.util.LoggerManager;

public class HACacheManager {
    private PersistentCacheManager pCacheManager;
    private Cache<String, Object> patientCache;

    public HACacheManager() {
        pCacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder
                            .newCacheManagerBuilder()
                            .with(CacheManagerBuilder
                                    .persistence(System.getProperty("java.io.tempdir")+File.separator+"haCache")).build();
        pCacheManager.init();
        pCacheManager.createCache("patientList-cache", CacheConfigurationBuilder
                                    .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                            String.class, 
                                            Pair.class, 
                                            ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(10).disk(100, MemoryUnit.MB, true)));
    }

    public CacheManager getHACacheManager() {
        return pCacheManager;
    }

    public Cache<String,Pair> getPatientCache() {
        return pCacheManager.getCache("patientList-cache", String.class, Pair.class);
    }
}
```

Then, I have used the cache as follows, elsewhere in my codebase:

```
// Check cache for existing data first
        HACacheManager cacheManager = new HACacheManager();
        Cache<String, Pair> patientCache = cacheManager.getPatientCache();
        String key = organizationId+","+startCount+","+recordCount; // Key based on method arguments
        if(patientCache.containsKey(key)) {
            return (Pair) patientCache.get(key);
        }
```

and then if the key is not found in the cache, then we create a new element in the cache:

```
    Pair returnPair = new Pair(patientCount, patientList); 
    patientCache.put(key, returnPair);
```

Now, the first time I call the action in struts2 in the browser, it displays the JSP correctly and the values that I have returned are displayed correctly, implying that they have also been set in the cache.

However, if I call the same action a second time, I get the following exception:

```
org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Persistence directory already locked by another process: D:\tools\eclipse-oxygen\eclipse\null\haCache
org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner$Transition.failed(StatusTransitioner.java:235)
org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.init(EhcacheManager.java:603)
net.ha.apserver.controller.HACacheManager.(HACacheManager.java:26)
net.ha.apserver.controller.UserManager.getUserPatients(UserManager.java:472)
net.ha.apserver.view.CohortSearchAction.getPatient(CohortSearchAction.java:853)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:352)
org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:171)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

At this point I have no choice but to restart the server since subsequent calls give the same exception. Is there some configuration that I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have initialised `HACacheManager` in your method i.e. called upon by the action. Every time you hit action, `cacheManager` is initialised. Ehcache won't allow creating the cache with same path twice.
Initialize once, by creating a static reference & use that reference in your action/method.

```
public static HACacheManager cacheManager = new HACacheManager();
```

Or better create a singleton instance. Put following lines in your `HACacheManager` class:

```
private static HACacheManager cacheManager = null;
public static HACacheManager getInstance() { 
    if (cacheManager == null) 
        cacheManager = new HACacheManager();
    return cacheManager; 
}
```

and call following method from your action/method(s):

```
HACacheManager cacheManager = HACacheManager.getInstance();
```

Comment: I guess it's better late than never. I did ultimately implement it this way, just hadn't mentioned it here.